# Is there a way to manage users' calendar appointments on App Engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to be able to book and manage appointments for users of my App Engine project. These appointments will be specific to my app and should not show up on the users' Google Calendars.

Is there an already existing service that I can leverage or will I have to build this out from scratch? What would be the recommended approach for building this from scratch?

EDIT: If I use the Google Calendar API, is there a way to keep all the user appointment data only on the app servers and not on the users' Google Calendars?

Comment: Google 'google calendar api'.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Google calendar API, their appointment data would automatically be kept up to date. If you imported it into an appengine database, it would not.

I see no need for you to reinvent the wheel to then duplicate the appointment that data when you could just as easily pull the most up to date information form the Google calendar API.

Comment: These appointments would be specific to my app and it would be too much to ask permission to access users' Google Calendars for this purpose. I am looking for a solution which I can implement within my app without interfering with users' Google Calendars.

Comment: You could make a separate calendar label in Google Calender and put all of your events under that label. That would prevent it from littering the user's view with these specific events. But it also gives you the convenience of google Calendar API

Comment: What about permissions? Wouldn't this require the permission to read and modify users' calendars?

Comment: Can I instead create new calendars for each user of my app just for managing appointments within my app?

Comment: Yes you would need those permissions, but the users would realize that it is for integration with Google Calendar.